# Correctly closing of polygons generated using skimage.measure.find_contours()

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm currently using `skimage.measure.find_contours()` to find contours on a surface. Now that I've found the contours I need to able to find the area enclosed within them.

When all of the vertices are within the data set this is fine as a have a fully enclosed polygon. 
However, how do I ensure the polygon is fully enclosed if the contour breaches the edge of the surface, either at an edge or at a corner? When this happens I would like to use the edge of the surface as additional vertices to close off the polygon. For example in the following image, with contours shown, you can see that the contours end at the edge of the image, how do I close them up? Also in the example of the brown contour, which is just a single line, I don't think I want an area returned, how would I single out this case?

[image: Contour example]

I know I can check for enclosed contours/polygons by checking if the last vertices of the polygon is the same as the first.

I have code for calculating the area inside a polygon, taken from [here](https://arachnoid.com/area_irregular_polygon/)

```
def find_area(array):
    a = 0
    ox,oy = array[0]
    for x,y in array[1:]:
        a += (x*oy-y*ox)
        ox,oy = x,y
    return -a/2
```

I just need help in closing off the polygons. And checking for the different cases that might occur.

Thanks

## Update:

After applying the solution suggested by @soupault I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import measure


# Construct some test data
x, y = np.ogrid[-np.pi:np.pi:100j, -np.pi:np.pi:100j]
r = np.sin(np.exp((np.sin(x)**3 + np.cos(y)**2)))

# Coordinates of point of interest
pt = [(49,75)]

# Apply thresholding to the surface
threshold = 0.8
blobs = r > threshold

# Make a labelled image based on the thresholding regions
blobs_labels = measure.label(blobs, background = 0)

# Show the thresholded regions
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(blobs_labels, cmap='spectral')

# Apply regionprops to charactersie each of the regions
props = measure.regionprops(blobs_labels, intensity_image = r)

# Loop through each region in regionprops, identify if the point of interest is
# in that region. If so, plot the region and print it's area.
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(r, cmap='Greys')
plt.plot(pt[0][0], pt[0][1],'rx')
for prop in props:
    coords = prop.coords
    if np.sum(np.all(coords[:,[1,0]] == pt[0], axis=1)):
        plt.plot(coords[:,1],coords[:,0],'r.')
        print(prop.area)
```

This solution assumes that each pixel is 1x1 in size. In my real data solution this isn't the case so I have also applied the following function to apply linear interpolation to the data. I believe you can also apply a similar function to make the area of each pixel smaller and increase the resolution of the data.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def interpolate_patch(x,y,patch):
    x_interp = np.arange(np.ceil(x[0]), x[-1], 1)
    y_interp = np.arange(np.ceil(y[0]), y[-1], 1)

    f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, patch, kind='linear')

    patch_interp = f(x_interp, y_interp)

    return x_interp, y_interp, patch_interp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to measure the properties of different regions, it is natural to start with finding the regions (not contours).

The algorithm will be the following, in this case:

1. Prepare a labeled image:

   1.a Either fill the areas between different contour lines with the different colors;

   1.b Or apply some image thresholding function, and then run `skimage.measure.label` (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label);
2. Execute `regionprops` using the very labeled image as an input (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops);
3. Iterate over regions in `regionprops` and calculate the desired parameters (area, perimeter, etc).

Once you identified the regions in your image via `regionprops`, you can call `.coords` for each of them to get the enclosed contour.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried reading up on your suggestion but I'm getting confused. I'm only interested in the areas enclosed by the contours shown in the image. How would I a) fill in these areas with different colours and b) identify which are regions of interest once all of the image has been split into regions? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think get what you mean now. My concern is that measure.regionprops takes only full pixels that meet the criteria, whereas measure.find_contours seems to do some interpolation and hence allows partial pixels to be within the region, given a larger area. Is there a way to compensate for this?

Comment: @jlt199 Regarding your first comment: (a) One of the ways is to `for i, c in enumerate(contours): rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], shape=img.shape); img_filled[rr, cc] = i`. This will not properly for the corner contours though. A better way would be to use the algorithm called "flood fill", but, unfortunately, we don't have it in `skimage` so far.

Comment: (b) This is an another complex question, and that's why thresholding + segmentation approach is, typically, a better fit. In that case, you, essentially, identify ROIs by intensity levels (high-intensity regions are of interest, others are background). In your example, you have both high- (cyan and blue contours at the bottom) and low-intensity (red and violet) regions, and your treat both of this sets as ROIs, which is very confusing.

Comment: Regarding the second comment: algorithms for subpixel processing are relatively rare in "popular" image processing, therefore I'd suggest not to consider this feature as important, at least, for now. Another point is that, typically, you should be very specific about what you count and do not count as your ROI. Relying on an algorithm which performs _some magic_ interpolation isn't a good idea. You should make the your problem (as well as your solution) as deterministic as possible (for example, quantize the image before the processing, threshold at a fixed intensity level, etc).

Comment: I was using this data set as an example and hadn't realised the contours were enclosing areas of high and low amplitude. My actual data doesn't display this behaviour. So, I am now using using the thresholding and labelling technique you describe, along with `regionprops` for measuring the regions. I am also using an interpolation function to apply linear interpolation to reduce the pixel size to get uniform pixel sizing and also greater resolution. So far this seems to be working well. Thanks for your help. I will update the thread with my solution code soon.

Answer (score 0):

If someone will need close open contours by image edges (and make a polygon) here is:

```python
import shapely.geometry as sgeo
import shapely.ops as sops


def close_contour_with_image_edge(contour, image_shape):
    """
    this function uses shapely because its easiest way to do that
    :param contour: contour generated by skimage.measure.find_contours()
    :param image_shape: tuple (row, cols), standard return of numpy shape()
    :return:
    """
    # make contour linestring
    contour_line = sgeo.LineString(contour)

    # make image box linestring
    box_rows, box_cols = image_shape[0], image_shape[1]
    img_box = sgeo.LineString(coordinates=(
        (0, 0),
        (0, box_cols-1),
        (box_rows-1, box_cols-1),
        (box_rows-1, 0),
        (0, 0)
    ))

    # intersect box with non-closed contour and get shortest line which touch both of contour ends
    edge_points = img_box.intersection(contour_line)
    edge_parts = sops.split(img_box, edge_points)
    edge_parts = list(part for part in edge_parts.geoms if part.touches(edge_points.geoms[0]) and part.touches(edge_points.geoms[1]))
    edge_parts.sort(reverse=False, key=lambda x: x.length)
    contour_edge = edge_parts[0]

    # weld it
    contour_line = contour_line.union(contour_edge)
    contour_line = sops.linemerge(contour_line)
    contour_polygon = sgeo.Polygon(contour_line.coords)

    return contour_polygon
```